# More apache processes = higher TTFB = lower money? why?

Tags: apache, memory, ttfb, upgrade

I just upgraded my server from 8 GB ram to 16 GB ram.

I then adjusted my apache settings to serve more users at a time including mobile. Yes I'm still on prefork mode because I created a module and I'm using PHP with mod_ruid2.

My settings before were:

```
Timeout 30
StartServers 25
MinSpareServers 25
MaxSpareServers 25
MinSpareServers 25
MaxSpareServers 25
ServerLimit 25
MaxClients 25
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
```

I now set them to the following to try to accomodate more users as well as occasional bots who manage to use up 2 server slots to download files:

```
Timeout 60
StartServers 100
MinSpareServers 100
MaxSpareServers 100
MinSpareServers 100
MaxSpareServers 100
ServerLimit 100
MaxClients 100
MaxRequestsPerChild 5000
```

I then tested my site with the exact same settings in webpagetest.org before and after the memory change. The new settings resulted in my TTFB being over 210 ms. The old settings resulted in my TTFB being between 80 and 110 ms.

I'm just curious as to why there's such a large difference and if there is any way I can reduce the TTFB without reducing the number of processes? or should I just reduce the processes and thus make some users wait forever to connect to the site?

Or could there be better settings I can use in my apache config?

Comment: Compute queue. You can only process as many processes as you have CPU for. For example, 4 quad core CPUs allow for 16 simultaneous computing processes, though many more can exist within the compute queue. This, with shorter a Quorum (typically 4) means that with enough processes in the queue, you will be swapping processes and pinging the swap file more. Increasing Quorum reduces swapping in the compute queue which is typical for more process intensive situations and less responsive to real-human users. It may be that you are trying to keep too many processes alive and swapping more.

Comment: With 100 start processes, it is possible that you are loading the compute queue too heavily with processes that are not actually doing anything for your users. Adjust to something around typical peak simultaneous user count. Also, keep in mind that you are capping your Apache process count to 100. I have found that the defaults are good, but smaller adjustments are sometimes required for busy sites. I also go back to using memory for Apache and MySQL cache. The effect of allocating a good chunk just for these speeds up your servers response ties radically. My system runs faster when loaded.

Comment: I don't see the point in having all of your values the same, this basically makes minspare and maxspare values useless as they are there in order for apache to keep an amount of workers waiting for new connections while not keep all of your workers active if they are not needed causing extra needed load. Start processes should be set to around the average number of workers you currently use to make sure that if apache needs to restart it will be able to handle all incoming requests once it restarts without the need to spawn new processes which would take extra time. 1/

Comment: Now depending on how much traffic you receive and if they coming in waves or spikes all within a short interval you should lower your minspare to a value in which you think will be enough to handle any spikes. You could leave maxspare as the same amount as your server limit, you are basically telling apache that it is allowed to keep all workers processes active but doing so without the need too will just cause extra load since each worker is an actual process running which is not needed if the worker is not being used. I wouldn't recommend leaving maxspare at your server limit 2/

Comment: especially if you plan on scaling this configuration in the future since during low traffic times apache would be able to keep all of its worker processes alive and without sufficient CPU resources you could tax your CPU with empty workers which just ads more sys cpu time since your CPU will be switching between all pids. Also why is min/max listed twice?

Comment: @Analog If you want to put this in an answer, I would certainly up-vote it! Twice if I can! ;-)  Cheers!!

Comment: So I guess that means I should only set the number of processes to eight? I have 2 cpu's and 4 threads. That's such a low number and if two items are downloaded at once by one bot and 5 bots come along, then users will be waiting a long time... not good.

Comment: ok so now I set startservers=8, minspareservers=8, and the upper limits to 32 and the timings made no difference. I noticed similar timings when running tests on my hosting company. Makes me wonder what to believe

Comment: you double your timeout - thats why, not?

Comment: Then I reverted it back but this time to 15 seconds because networks are fast and I don't want people holding up available apache slots too long.

Comment: I was saying that only 8 processes,using your example, can actually do anything physically within your computer at a time. I was not suggesting that you set your start servers that low. I was suggesting that your initial default value was likely okay and that if you were to adjust it, adjust it to your average daily peek users per second if it is greater than the start server value. In other words, if you rper second user count were to go beyond 25, then consider raising your start servers.

Comment: Your start servers are resident ready processes which remain live whether they are tasked to do anything or not. These processes remain within the compute queue and never leave. In one respect, it is good to have enough to avoid process load times, however, having too many means that all of the non-utilized processes need to be maintained which means swapping in and out of the compute queue along with processes that are actually doing something. Process priorities can dictate how some of this goes of course, however, processes will get promoted eventually even with low priorities.

Comment: I start to wonder if webpagetest.org is making false tests again. I'm gonna monitor things over time and see.